# How to get the current time as 13-digit integer in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have this `jQuery` function that returns the current time as the number of milliseconds since the epoch (Jan 1, 1970):

```
time = new Date().getTime();
```

Is there a way to do the same in Ruby?

Right now, I am using Ruby's `Time.now.to_i` which works great but returns a **10-digit** integer (number of seconds)

How can I get it to display the number of milliseconds, as in `jQuery`?

Comment: That isn't a "jQuery function", it's just plain ECMAScript (javascript). Perhaps that's what prompted the -1, bit harsh though.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/20001883/238886

Answer (score 188):

```
require 'date'

p DateTime.now.strftime('%s') # "1384526946" (seconds)
p DateTime.now.strftime('%Q') # "1384526946523" (milliseconds)
```

Comment: Note for Rails users: the `strftime` method provided by `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` does not include the `%s` and `%Q` specifiers. You'll need to convert to a plain Ruby `DateTime` first, using the `to_datetime` method.

Comment: @LonnonFoster Now it works (just tested in Rails console).

Comment: Hi, how can I do the same thing, but not for now, but rather from a date field?

Comment: Found this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24149463/ruby-strftimeq-broken

Comment: Note that this truncates rather than rounding (as you can see from the example — 1384526946523ms should round up to 1384526947s).

Answer (score 117):

Javascript's `gettime()` returns the number of milliseconds since epoch.

Ruby's `Time.now.to_i` will give you the number of seconds since epoch. If you change that to `Time.now.to_f`, you still get seconds but with a fractional component. Just multiply that by 1,000 and you have milliseconds. Then use `#to_i` to convert it to an integer. And you end up with:

```
(Time.now.to_f * 1000).to_i
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! Still new to this whole thing... Don't know which answer to mark as the correct one actually...

Comment: Just for further information, `Time.now` comes from Ruby since `Time.current` comes from Rails. Thus `Time.current` is acknowledged by Rails application timezone and `Time.now` is using server timezone. In my experience, always use `Time.current` on your Rails application for timezone consistency

Comment: No, you shouldn't use `Time.current` here at all, it takes longer to construct, and since you are immediately converting it to a unix timestamp, you do not care at all about time zone consistency. (Unix timestamps always relate to UTC). So, while what you're saying is true in 99% of the cases, this one performance-wise falls in the last 1%.

Comment: This is my preferred approach. One thing I like to do is augment the Time class to add an ```:epoch``` method:

    class Time
      def epoch
        (self.to_f * 1000).to_i
      end
    end

Comment: @brauliobo Care to elaborate how it fakes milliseconds? Your statement is misleading, OP's answer is absolutely right.

Comment: @coisnepe https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Time.html#method-i-strftime . to_f is an approximation. See my answer to this question. -1 to this answer for accuracy problems.

Answer (score 34):

`(Time.now.to_f * 1000).to_i` should do the same thing.

Comment: @brauliobo what's fake milliseconds?

Comment: @brauliobo It doesn't, since `to_f` includes milliseconds as a decimal.

Comment: See https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Time.html#method-i-strftime . to_f is an approximation. Don't use it. See my answer to this question. -1 for accuracy problems.

Answer (score 29):

Using [`strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Time.html#method-i-strftime), you can get the number of seconds and append fractional milliseconds (or smaller units, if needed):

```
2.2.2 :001 > t = Time.new
 => 2015-06-02 12:16:56 -0700 
2.2.2 :002 > t.strftime('%s%3N')
 => "1433272616888"
```

Note though that this doesn't round, it truncates, as you can see with `to_f` or if you go out to microseconds:

```
2.2.2 :003 > t.to_f
 => 1433272616.888615
2.2.2 :004 > t.usec
 => 888615
```

and the `to_f` / `to_i` solution has the same problem (`to_i` doesn't round, it [truncates](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Float.html#method-i-to_i)):

```
2.2.2 :009 > (t.to_f * 1000).to_i
 => 1433272616888
```

so if you really care about millisecond accuracy, a better bet may be `to_f` with [`round`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Float.html#method-i-round):

```
2.2.2 :010 > (t.to_f * 1000).round
 => 1433272616889
```

That said, as [noted in the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Time.html#method-i-to_f), "IEEE 754 double is not accurate enough to represent the number of nanoseconds since the Epoch", so if you really *really* care, consider [`to_r`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Time.html#method-i-to_r) instead of `to_f` --

```
2.2.2 :011 > (t.to_r * 1000).round
 => 1433272616889
```

-- although if you're only rounding to milliseconds you're probably fine.

Answer (score 20):

Be careful, don't get confused. The fact that Ruby supports the idea of fractional seconds as a float doesn't actually make it a floating point number. I got into trouble with this when I was doing Wireshark timestamp time comparisons in Python... the time calculations in the pcap-ng just weren't working. It was only when I treated the two parts (integral seconds and integral nanoseconds) as both integers was I able to get proper numbers.

That's because floating point numbers have [Accuracy problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems). Indeed, a quick bit of Ruby will show you that to_f does not equal, say, nsec:

```
irb(main):019:0> t=Time.now
=> 2015-04-10 16:41:35 -0500
irb(main):020:0> puts "#{t.to_f}; #{t.nsec}"
1428702095.1435847; 143584844
```

Caveat Programmer. You may be safe to 3 significant digits, but the fact remains: Floating point numbers on computers are approximations. The nanosecond counters on modern computers are integers.

Comment: The better response. Thank you. The directive format ```.strftime("%9N")``` also can be used.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Time.html#method-i-strftime

Answer (score 12):

Get a [Time](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Time.html) object with `Time.now`, calling `#to_i` returns a Unix timestamp (seconds from epoch).  `#to_f` gives fractional seconds which you can use to get milliseconds from epoch:

```
Time.now.to_f * 1000
```

Comment: this fakes the milliseconds

Comment: @brauliobo How does this "fake milliseconds"? Did you take the time to execute the code and check for yourself?

Comment: @coisnepe maybe so, maybe not- but I did. Read my response above, and also steenslag's proper methods in his answer. -1 to this answer, because to_f is an approximation that appears to work but isn't really the milliseconds from the system's nanosecond counter.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Process.clock_gettime`:

```rb
>> Process.clock_gettime(Process::CLOCK_REALTIME, :millisecond)
=> 1644588106765
```

See https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Process.html#method-c-clock_gettime

Answer (score -1):

The typecast Integer(1e6*Time.now.to_f) returns a Bignum that can hold the milliseconds

Comment: I don't like to_f. It's an approximation. Read my answer to this question. -1 for accuracy problems. Programmers are likely to get into a bad habit of thinking to_f is for real.