# Ruby convert DateTime to milliseconds

Tags: ruby, date

How do I convert this JavaScript function to Ruby?

```
new Date().getTime()
```

That returns:

> 1384520363488

I’m having trouble getting the same answer using Ruby DateTime, TimeAt, etc.