# Ruby strftime("%Q") broken?

Tags: ruby

The [`strftime` docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime) claim that `%Q` works:

```
%Q - Number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
```

But it returns "%Q" for me.

```
2.1.1 :054 > date = Time.now
 => 2014-06-10 12:28:57 -0700
2.1.1 :055 > date.strftime("%Q")
 => "%Q"
```

I'm using RVM and Ruby 2.1.1.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a Ruby bug?

Comment: `%Q` is not listed for `Time` object, but for `Date`.

Comment: Arup is right. You can simply convert `Time` instance with `to_date` method and then use *%Q* formatting flag.

Comment: Just as a piece of advice: Before thinking you've you've discovered a bug in a core library, it's always good to dig into the docs, ask around why something that should work doesn't, and, if the docs and your code seem correct, then *maybe* consider it's a bug. Odds are good though, that finding bugs in highly tested libraries won't happen. Instead, the bugs will be in your code the vast majority of the time. But, don't worry, we've all done that at least once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're declaring a `Time` object, not a `Date` or `DateTime` object. `Time`'s behavior is entirely different from `Date` or `DateTime`'s.

Try this instead:

```
require 'date'
Date.today.strftime("%Q")
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 7):

Other answers mentioned how to do it with DateTime, but if you prefer to use a Time object (e.g. because [Rubocop's default settings complain about using DateTime.now](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/DateTime)), then this is equivalent:

`Time.now.strftime("%s%L")`

`%s` is seconds since the Epoch, and `%L` is milliseconds of the current second.

Comment: This is bang on and exactly what I needed. I was coming here also because Rubocop doesn't like `to_datetime`.

Comment: why is this not part of Time, if it's that simple?

Answer (score 4):

`'%Q'` is used by Date and DateTime objects, not a Time object. You can try this:

```
require 'date'
DateTime.now.strftime("%Q")
```

or

```
require 'date'
Date.today.strftime("%Q")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert a time object to DateTime since `%Q` is only used by Date or DateTime

```
Time.now.to_datetime.strftime('%Q')
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing, that no answers mentioned, why you got back `"%Q"`. You could also get *error*, while directives are not supported, but you are trying to pass.

[`Time#strftime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime) explicitly mentioned about this -

> The directives begin with a percent (%) character. **Any text not listed as a directive will be passed through to the output string.**