# Is it normal for js console and rails console to print the same time differently?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, datetime, time, console

I have a date_time October 5th, 2000, 00:00. Printing it with the js console and the rails console return the same first six digits, but then the js console adds three zeros at the end. Should this be expected behavior?

```
var date = new Date(2000, 10, 5);
date.getTime();
=> 970722000000


Date.new(2000,10,5).to_time.to_i
=> 970722000
```

Comment: They are not different, they are same, except JS time is in milliseconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tushar said, javascript's Date.getTime returns milliseconds.

You can see the reference for the Date class here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

It's not obvious how to get a Unix timestamp from that page, but apparently there is a Date.now() function that is supported post IE 8: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.4

So for Javascript:

```
Date.now()     //seconds - this doesn't seem to work, despite what Google says
Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000) //so for seconds you're probably stuck with this
Date.getTime() //milliseconds
```

The corresponding millisecond and second timestamps for Ruby are elaborated here: [How to get the current time as 13-digit integer in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148888/how-to-get-the-current-time-as-13-digit-integer-in-ruby)

To plagiarize the top answer there:

```
require 'date'

p DateTime.now.strftime('%s') # "1384526946" (seconds)
p DateTime.now.strftime('%Q') # "1384526946523" (milliseconds)
```

Comment: Are you sure about `Date.now()`? That returns "Uncaught TypeError: Date.now is not a function(…)" for me.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, it doesn't even work in my browser (it just returns the milliseconds for me). Updated